# How to increase the height of a div based on the content?

Tags: css

I have a div inside which there is a student registration form including textboxes , dropdown, etc. Now few elements like two or three textboxes wont appear in every form. how to dynamically set the height based on the content using css

Comment: the height will be automatically calculated. Just don't set a certain height in the first place. Also, like @SureshPonnukalai said: post your code within the question.

Comment: you can use `min-height` for minimal height display. Or may be somewhere for parent div you used `overflow:hidden`.

Comment: show html - you will get an answer

Answer (score 0):

You can set height as auto in your css. This will increase the height of your div depending upon the content.

```
<div id=div1 class=content1> <div id=div2>
<form>
<label>First Name</label>
<input type=text>
<label>Last Name</label>
<input type=text>
<label>Last Name</label>
<input type=text>
<label>Last Name</label>
<input type=text>
</form>
</div></div>
<style>
#div2{
 width:300px;
 height:auto;
}
</style>
```

Above is the example of inline css. You can also use external or internal css.

Comment: Have checked the id or class used in the div and that used in your css are same or not??

Comment: I tried it and it worked. Make sure that you have given some content in the division. And if possible can you please post your code here?

Comment: <div id=div1 class=content1> <div id=div2 style="height:auto>//html form inside the div</div></div>

Comment: <div id=div1 class=content1>My Test Content<br>My Test Content <div>
<style>
#div1{
background-color:blue;
width:100px;
height:auto;
}
</style>

Comment: i want to add height auto for the inner div how do i do that

Comment: i added this way in css for the inner div div2 but height auto not working

Comment: You need to add width as well. I have updated my answer, try doing it that way. It worked for me.

Comment: i applied this way still not working . content2{
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    margin-top: 12px;
}



<div id=outerdiv >

<div id=innerdiv class=content2>

// html code for form goes here

</div>


</div>

Comment: You must be getting all your form fields in horizontal line. Am I right?? simply give width in the css. And it will work.

Comment: . content2{
    height: auto;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    margin-top: 12px;
}



<div id=outerdiv >
<div id=innerdiv class=content2>
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>First Name</td>
<td><input type=text></td>
<td>Last Name</td>
<td><input type=text></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Last Name</td>
<td><input type=text></td>
<td>Last Name</td>
<td><input type=text></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>

Comment: my code appears this way still even applying width wont set height to auto

Comment: Do you want all your form fields to appear one after the other in vertical order??

Comment: No in a table row of two. means in one row will have 2 fields

Comment: So what is the problem you are facing right now. I executed your code and I got two rows containing two fields.

Comment: div height should increase based on the content

Comment: I increased the number of rows.It increased its height.Can you give me the code which is not working.I mean when you increase the content and you find that div height not increasing.So that I can understand where the problem is.

Comment: think it might be due to other css then will check that . thanks a lot